# Write to a QTcpSocket from an other thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, sockets, send

I'm currently facing a problem in my game that I'm writing using Qt. I have this QTcpSocket to communicate with the game server, and some AI running in an other thread.

The problem is that when I want to send some data to the server from the AI thread, I get the following error:

> QSocketNotifier: Socket notifiers cannot be enabled or disabled from another thread

Is there a way to get around this issue?

Comment: Emit signal from AI, catch this signal in another thread and write all what you need.

Comment: You should only access `QTcpSocket` from the thread it lives in. If you want to read/write from another thread, you will need to use Signals/Slots.

Comment: Use signals and slots for communication across threads in Qt.

Comment: That looks like a good idea, but wouldn't that create a dependency to my AI in my QTcpSocket? (by that, I mean that I will need a reference to my AI object in the connection)

Comment: @Phito Not necessarily. If all you do in the module handling the TCP connection is to send signals, than you don't need a reference to your AI module. The connections will be created in the AI module and the module handling the TCP socket will just send signals and, as a result, post events in the AI module's event loop.

Comment: @luliu sadly I use the connection module in other places than in the IA. So I need to be able to call the "send" function of this module from any thread